# Need help fixing my javascript "for loop" to play an audio playlist

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I'm working on a very simple audio playlist that automatically plays each song after the previous one has finished. I am using pure javascript and the html5 audio tag. How can I fix this code up so it works properly?

```js
var i = ['first.mp3', 'second.mp3', 'third.mp3'];
function playlist() {
   for (var i=0; i<2; i++)
}
```

```html
<audio controls="controls" preload="none" onended="playlist()">
<source src="first.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
<audio controls="controls" preload="none" onended="playlist()">
<source src="second.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
<audio controls="controls" preload="none" onended="playlist()">
<source src="third.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

Comment: What you writing inside for loop? I guess it should be `for(var i=0; i<3; i++)` firstly.

Comment: If `i<2` then play next audio

Comment: it does not make any sense. Can you please elaborate what you have done to achieve what you need?

Comment: If you want to go for a playlist..why not to use a single audio tag..and set `src` to another once a mp3 finishes/ends.

Comment: I have say 10 mp3s I want to make a playlist out of. I included `onended="playlist()"` event handler to fire off my function that has the argument `for` which is suppose to increment the array of mp3s by one song after the next.

Answer (score 0):

Better way to `loop`

HTML

```
<audio id="audio" controls preload>
    <source src="/files/5913/7240/6617/html5-audio-loop.ogg">
    <source src="/files/5513/7240/6617/html5-audio-loop.wav">
    <source src="/files/8013/7240/6617/html5-audio-loop.mp3">
</audio>
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('audio').addEventListener('ended', function(){
this.currentTime = 0;
this.play();
}, false);
```